# Jboss JMX-Console

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

Is there any way to change login authentication dialog of JMX -console like changing "Username" string to "administrator" and adding some text to the dialog?  I googled this but could not find anything

Comment: what version of JBoss? EAP 5 or AS 6?

Answer (score 0):

The JBoss 4 documentation here shows how to change the JMX user and password, in the jmx-console-users.properties file. More info here:

https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Inspecting_the_Server___the_JMX_Console_Web_Application-Securing_the_JMX_Console.html

You could change the source of the jmx console or you could write a JMX browser as shown here in the documentation.

https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Connecting_to_the_JMX_Server-Connecting_to_JMX_Using_RMI.html